# Android and IOs performance differenence in Ionic

Tags: android, ios, performance, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to build reporting app that has so much of data. But the app is running well in Samsung Tab 2 while on iPad, it is having performance issues. For eg while showing and hiding elements, it is showing flickering effects. Also, I have designed custom loader which is lagging in iPad while works fine on android os. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you